# jquery timer doesnt show div that is clicked instead it navigates to div based on timer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am toggling each 4 divs for 10 seconds using this jQuery function based on `a href id` value.

The timer works fine and it changes 4 divs for every 10 seconds but when user clicks a particular div it doesn't navigate to particular div and stays there for a given period(ex 10 sec) and proceeds to next div from current div instead of that it goes to div based on timer value.

Can anyone help me regarding this?

```
$(function() {
    $("a.menu").click(function() {
        $("div.featuredposts_content").hide();
        $($(this).attr('href')).show();
        return false;
    });
});

$(function() {
    var counter = 0,
        divs = $('#cat1, #cat2, #cat3,#cat4');

    function showDiv() {
        divs.hide() // hide all divs
        .filter(function(index) {
            return index == counter % 4;
        }) // figure out correct div to show
        .show('fast'); // and show it
        counter++;
    }; // function to loop through divs and show correct div
    showDiv(); // show first div    
    setInterval(function() {
        showDiv(); // show next div
    }, 15 * 1000); // do this every 10 seconds    
});​
```

Comment: where is the onclick event code for the divs?

Comment: $(function () {
         $("a.menu").click(function () {
             $("div.featuredposts_content").hide();
             $($(this).attr('href')).show();
             return false;
         });
          });

Comment: Please explain what you need in short sentences.

Comment: I am using timer to navigate divs with help of <a href="#id">.At present if the users click div3 if timer shows div1 it goes to div2.but my requirement is if the users clicks div3 from div1 it has show div3 and move to div4 .

Comment: Have you tried to set your counter to the div number?

Comment: `but when user clicks a particular div it doesn't navigate to particular div` In your code you have no click event attached to any divs. You are having a click event attached to an anchor tag with a class of `menu` - `a.menu`. Can you post the relevant HTML please. As your code stands now there is no visible click event attached to any of the divs. If possible you can also look into setting up a fiddle on jsFiddle.net to showcase the issue. This one can get you started, just fill in your HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/KRYvg/ and post the link to the fiddle in your question.

Comment: i am trying like counter = divs.index($(this)); but it is not working.

Comment: My html is like this basically <a href=#cat1">cat1</a> <div id="Cat1">Category1</div>

Comment: @sai: I used your HTML fragments and put something together which shows how to store the index of the div you show after you clicked the anchor. See my answer for more details. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed the exact mark-up from the fragments posted in the comments.

First I think you should re-set your counter after each full cycle otherwise it will grow, grow, grow and eventual could cause an exception, maybe not within the first 2-3 days but eventually. There is no need to have the `counter` variable go beyond `divs.length`.

Aside that the only thing really missing from your code was the setting of the counter value inside your click event:

```
$("a.menu").click(function() {
    $("div.featuredposts_content").hide();
    var $divToShow = $($(this).attr('href'));
    $divToShow.show();
    
    // save the index of the new div +1 to ensure it moves on to the div thereafter
    counter = divs.index($divToShow) + 1; 
    
    return false;
});
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u78Uc/) - Timer continues from selected div

(I shortened the timer in the DEMO for demonstration purpose you should off course re-set it to your original value)

I used the following assumed HTML:

```
<a href="#cat1" class="menu">cat1</a>
<a href="#cat2" class="menu">cat2</a>
<a href="#cat3" class="menu">cat3</a>
<a href="#cat4" class="menu">cat4</a>
<div id="cat1" class="featuredposts_content">Category1</div>
<div id="cat2" class="featuredposts_content">Category2</div>
<div id="cat3" class="featuredposts_content">Category3</div>
<div id="cat4" class="featuredposts_content">Category4</div>
```

​
This is the complete script:

```
$(function() {
    var counter = 0;
    var divs = $('#cat1, #cat2, #cat3, #cat4');

    function showDiv() {
        divs.hide() // hide all divs
        .filter(function(index) {
            return index == counter % divs.length;
        }) // figure out correct div to show
        .show('fast'); // and show it
        if(counter == divs.length){
            counter = 1;
        } else {
            counter++
        }
    }; // function to loop through divs and show correct div
    showDiv(); // show first div    
    setInterval(function() {
        showDiv(); // show next div
    }, 2000); // do this every 10 seconds    
    
    $("a.menu").click(function() {
        $("div.featuredposts_content").hide();
        var $divToShow = $($(this).attr('href'));
        $divToShow.show();
        
        counter = divs.index($divToShow) + 1;
        
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: @sai: Has this helped you at all or you still having this issue?